# Why does this code work in finding the first non-duplicate letter in a string?

Tags: javascript, string, function, indexof, lastindexof

I'm doing some self practice with Javascript.

I'm working on a question that asks me to find the first letter in a string that does not have a duplicate.

After some playing around, I finally got it to work using indexOf and lastIndexOf. But even though I made a working solution, I just dont understand how my solution works.

It seems like if I grabbed two of the same letters it SHOULDN'T return the first non duplicate letter. but it does. ***In other words, I cant explain how the if statement is returning a non duplicate letter.***

heres what I got:

```js
function noRepeat(str) {
  strSplit = str.split("");

  for (let i = 0; i < strSplit.length; i++) {
    if (strSplit.indexOf(strSplit[i]) === strSplit.lastIndexOf(strSplit[i])) {
      return strSplit[i];
    }
  }
}
console.log(noRepeat("yoboTyoboznopno"));
```

Comment: You go from zero up, and check for each if first index equal to last index. one you found it you return it and cut the script. Then yes, it gonna return the first no-repeating letter

Comment: If the lastIndexOf method reaches the currently iterated character, it means that it failed to find any other, which means that it has to be unique.